# What time and where on earth is the latest solar noon?

Tags: the-sun, time

For context: I am visiting Portugal from Australia and after observing that people tend to start their days later, I realised that solar noon also seems to occur at a later time - about 1.20pm at the moment. I don't recall solar noon every occurring at such a late time in Australia. When and where is the latest solar noon on earth?

Comment: This really is more about local definitions of time relative to Zulu than about anything astronomical.

Answer (score 7):

That should be in western China, since all of China uses Beijing's time zone.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_China

--- Edit below ---

In response to the comment by @adrianmcmenamin: I'll leave this as guesswork since I simply don't know the peculiarities of every timezone there is. Here's a back-of-the-envelope calculation for local noon in western China.

The Sun covers 15 degrees in a period of 1 hour. All of China is on Beijing time (UTC + 8 hours). With the above, it's centred on $15 \cdot 8 = 120^{\circ}$ east. As a consistency check, Beijing is at $116^{\circ}$ east. The westernmost part of China is at about $73^\circ$ east ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China#Landscape_and_climate)). Local noon there is delayed by $(120^\circ - 73^\circ)/(15^\circ/h) \simeq 3h$.

So, local noon is a little later than 3pm. This is discounting daylight savings time, which is not currently observed in China.

Comment: Please don't make guesses by way of answers. This would have been better as a comment.

Comment: Kashgar, China, which is just about the westernmost town in China, experiences solar noon around the beginning of February at about 3:10 PM, so I guess my answer of Adak, Alaska doesn't quite make it.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a neighbourhood of the South Pole. You use New Zealand time there, but the longitude varies from 0 to 360 degrees, so the solar noon is at midnight at some places. And also in some regions of northern Antarctica there are deviations in solar noon up to 7 hours, because time zones are very large there.
But if you want some inhabited civil settlement, it's St George, USA, Aleut islands - solar noon happens there around 15:02 - 15:27 in warm period, and also this is the farthest from poles inhabited place (and probably any land) with midnight sun - from 5 Jul to 14 Jul the Sun sets there around midnight and rises around 6:30 am, even though it's on the same latitude with Riga and Edinburgh. In Jigenxiang, the westernmost settlement in China, solar noon is on 15:17 in February. Then, theoretically, in westernmost point of China, solar noon is around 15:19 in February.
**Actually Attu, Canada has 15:37 solar noon on 10-11 March (but St George still has farthest from poles polar day - in Attu latest sunset is at 23:56)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that honor may belong to Adak, Alaska where solar noon does not occur during DST until 2:52 PM, or 1:52 Standard Time. All of Alaska is on Juneau time. You can check it [here](http://www.sunrisesunset.com/usa/Alaska.asp).
**Edit:**There are maps [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2572317/Are-YOU-living-sync-Amazing-map-reveals-manmade-timezones-countries-false-sense-sun-rises.html) that show the offset between local and solar time. It's pretty informative. There may be other areas besides western China where solar noon is very late (maybe I'll modify a spreadsheet and see if I can some up with something).

Comment: Please see my comment to the answer provided by @Alex. Western China seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: We'll both be wrong if someone in the central Pacific decides to move their country to the other side of the international dateline - noon will be 24 hours off :-) Great map in the link, btw.

Answer (score 3):

It is also very late in Vigo, Spain: https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/spain/vigo
Solar noon is at 2.40 pm by the end of July and at 1.50 pm in mid-February (due to DST, otherwise, would be 2.50 pm). Should Spain decide to live with DST (Europe will probably stop moving clocks soon, according to their vote) North-Western part of Spain will live with solar noons occurring at about 3 pm all the year round ;)
image: [image]the solar path around the year

Answer (score 1):

It was Kashgar in China back in 1991 when there was DST.  Noon occured at 4:10 pm and sunrise and 8:30 am and sunset at 11:45 pm. Civil twilight continued even after midnight.

Answer (score 1):

Made me look. On October 15 Portugal was still observing daylight saving time. The local time for continental Portugal was one hour later than UTC and the country is about 8 degrees west longitude, which adds another 32 minutes, but the equation of time on October 15 subtracts 14 minutes. The Sun should be due south at 1:04 PM plus or minus as much as 4 minutes depending on location within the country.

Answer (score 1):

I personally set my clock when i'm in holiday vacation putting my clock to Zone from UTC+8:00 to UTC+14:00 having twilight:10:00 AM-11:30 AM (morning) then 0:30 AM-1:45 AM with solar noon close to 17:45 and Sunrise and Sunset  11:45 AM to 12:45 AM (next calendar day) i do this to accommodate with my friends who lives in Los Angeles...

Answer (score -1):

I from Philippines experimented the biggest daylight saving time and i did get a sunrise of 11:45 am or 12:00 pm and solar noon occured at 7:30 pm and twilight continues even until the next calendar day it was on between 2019-2020

Comment: Are you saying the the official time in the Phillipines in 2019-2020 was such that the sun rose at 11:45?  That would be ... surprising, and would require a source. Or are you saying that you personnally set your clock forward?

Comment: The Philippines uses [UTC +08](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/philippines) and [As of 2020, the Philippines does not observe daylight saving time, although it was enforced for short periods during the presidency of Manuel L. Quezon in 1936-1937, Ramon Magsaysay in 1954, Ferdinand Marcos in 1978,and Corazon Aquino in 1990.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Asia#Philippines) It doesn't have on overly huge range of longitudes, so I don't think this can be correct.